# Automatically inputting function arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write an automated function that inputs given a list of other functions, will automatically call each function in the list. With that being said, some of the functions require different arguments. How can I get the arguments needed for each function to input them automatically?

If I create a module for import later:

```
def foo1(x):
    return x

def foo2(x):
    return x**2

def foo3(x, y):
    return x * y
```

So if I had a module with the functions above, then I can call each function in that module in a different script.

```
import module 

lst = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']

for func in lst:
    bar = getattr(module, func)
    bar(x)
```

In that last case, the function would require two arguments, x and y, but my code can only support one. How do I get that second argument in there automatically?

Comment: Using Python's [star magic](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work using keyword args (kwargs).

```py
import module 

dct = {'foo1': {"x": 1}, 'foo2': {"x": 1}, 'foo3': {"x": 1, "y": 2}}

for func, kwargs in dct.items():
    bar = getattr(module, func)
    bar(**kwargs)
```

Alternatively you could use positional args (args)

```py
import module 

dct = {'foo1': [1], 'foo2': [1], 'foo3': [1, 2]}

for func, args in dct.items():
    bar = getattr(module, func)
    bar(*args)
```